# How to repeat calculation on a subset of a database

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply

I have a large data frame, with many transects and for each of those transect I want to calculate for each year the intercept of the cros (x) and the value (y). Then I want to know how the intercept changed over the different years. I know how to calculate the intercept, however I have a lot of transects and I have to repeat this a lot, and I would like to do that more automatically.

So this is how my data looks like:

**df**

```
   transects year cros value
    10    1996   11    -3
    10    1996   12     5
    10    2005   11    -9
    10    2005   12    -3
    10    2010   11    -8
    10    2010   12    -8
    11    1996   11     7
    11    1996   12    -4
    11    2005   11    -6
    11    2005   12     9
    11    2010   11     6
    11    2010   12    17
    12    1996   14   -16
    12    1996   15   -17
    12    2005   14   -18
    12    2005   15   -11
    12    2010   14    16
    12    2010   15     7
```

So I made a function, to subset the dataset and to do some calculation with this subset.

Here is the code. I used `lapply` because I want the outcome of the code to put in a `list`. However it could be that `lapply` is not the right function for this problem.

```
 transect <- c(10, 11, 12)  

o <- lapply(1:length(transect), function(i) {
        s101 <- subset(df, along == transect[[i+1]])
```

# I want to create a subset for every transect and with that subset I want to do multiple calculations.

# Dune volume

# This makes sure that I have an intercept, also if there is no value above the 3

```
AUC96<-0 
 AUC05<-0
 AUC10<-0

 # Here I calculate the intercept for the different years.

     d96 <- subset(s101, (cros >= 3.00) & (year == 1996))
     AUC96<-sintegral(d96$cros,d96$value)$int
     lengthdune96 <- max(d96$value)-min(d96$value)
     AUC962 <- lengthdune96*8.00
     AUC96 <- AUC96 +AUC962

     d05 <- subset(s101, (cros >= 3.00) & (year == 2005))
     AUC05<-sintegral(d05$cros,d05$value)$int
     lengthdune05 <- max(d05$alti)-min(d05$value)
     AUC052 <- lengthdune05*8.00
     AUC05 <- AUC05 +AUC052

     d10 <- subset(s101, (cros >= 3.00) & (year == 2010))
     AUC10<-sintegral(d10$cros,d10$value)$int
     lengthdune10 <- max(d05$value)-min(d05$value)
     AUC102 <- lengthdune10*8.00
     AUC10 <- AUC10 +AUC102

     # Here the difference between the years
     dune96.05 <- AUC05-AUC96
     dune05.10 <- AUC10-AUC05

  c(transect[[i+1]], dune96.05, dune05.10)                              
   })
   out <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, o))
```

However when I try this I get this **error**:

```
`Error in approx(x, fx, n = 2 * n.pts + 1) :
      need at least two non-NA values to interpolate`
```

This is the first time that I try to make such a function, so it could be that I am doing this totally wrong. I hope that you can help me.

EDIT:

So after I changed the answer a bit, because that did not totally worked out. However I still get a error message and I am really stuck. I also tried different ways to solve this questions, eg looking at the plyr package, however I still get the same error questions:

So this is how my code looked like:

```
test<-lapply(unique(df$transect),function(i){s101 <- subset(df,df$transect==i)
{

  AUC96<-0
  AUC05<-0
  AUC10<-0

 d96 <- subset(s101, (cros >= 3.00) & (year == 1996))
 AUC96<-sintegral(d96$cros,d96$value)$int
 lengthdune96 <- max(d96$value)-min(d96$value)
 AUC962 <- lengthdune96*8.00
 AUC96 <- AUC96 +AUC962

 d05 <- subset(s101, (cros >= 3.00) & (year == 2005))
 AUC05<-sintegral(d05$cros,d05$value)$int
 lengthdune05 <- max(d05$alti)-min(d05$value)
 AUC052 <- lengthdune05*8.00
 AUC05 <- AUC05 +AUC052

 d10 <- subset(s101, (cros >= 3.00) & (year == 2010))
 AUC10<-sintegral(d10$cros,d10$value)$int
 lengthdune10 <- max(d05$value)-min(d05$value)
 AUC102 <- lengthdune10*8.00
 AUC10 <- AUC10 +AUC102

 dune96.05 <- AUC05-AUC96
 dune05.10 <- AUC10-AUC05
```

}

```
c(i,dune96.05, dune05.10)    
})
```

However I still get this error message:

```
`Error in approx(x, fx, n = 2 * n.pts + 1) :
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate`
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong, the function should work like this. I hope that somebody can help me.

Comment: No reason to reinvent the wheel. Have a look at package `plyr`. It offers functions to easily do things by subject and combine the result.

Comment: Good answers are always hard to give if you do not make a small toy example. You can use `by()` to do calculations for levels of a factor `year` inside a dataframe.

Comment: The example `df` does not contain the column `alti`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein sorry I forgot to change that alti means value, I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your use of lapply. You index *transect* as a list (it's a vector) and do not pass it (nor df) as an argument to your function in lapply, hence no luck with the subsetting. Try something like this:

```
lapply(unique(df$transect),function(i,df){s101 <- subset(df,transect==i)
,...
c(i, dune96.05, dune05.10)     
},df)
```

Comment: I added the curly bracket after the comma, which was missing. However now I do not get any results, I run the code and nothing happens. However I would like to get a list of the result, wich I can use.

Comment: what kind of 'nothing' happens? no messages? what about *out*, doesn't it contain your list?

Comment: Oh yeah I figured out what was wrong, my variable name was wrong... However I still get an error message:Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  unused argument (list(cros = c(30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195, 200, etc. I am not sure why i get this value, the variable cros is not used in the function, I am not really sure how to solfe it.